# jQuery UI Tabs not disposing of resources

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, colorbox, jquery-ui-tabs

I have three pages, `admin.php`, `user_admin.php`, and `client_admin.php` with corresponding JS source files `admin.js`, `user_admin.js`, and `client_admin.js`, and I'm having a problem with jQuery UI's tabs not disposing of resources properly.

`admin.php` is a placeholder for `user_admin.php` and `client_admin.php`, where each one of those is set up as a tab that is loaded dynamically. Here is the body for `admin.php`:

```
<body>
    <div id="tabs" style="width: 1000px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="user_admin.php">User Admin</a></li>
            <li><a href="client_admin.php">Client Admin</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="user_admin">
        </div>
        <div id="client_admin">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

with the following code to initialize jQuery-UI tabs:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs(
{
    cookie      : { expires: 9999 },
    cache       : false,
    ajaxOptions :
    {
        error : function( xhr, status, index, anchor )
        {
            $( anchor.hash ).html( "Error: could not load this tab" );
        }
    },
    show : function( event, ui )
    {
        previous_tab = ui.index;
        $( "#ui-tabs-" + previous_tab ).empty();
    }
});
```

The problem lies in `user_admin.php`, where I'm including `colorbox` and attaching it to links (with href's to the page that I want to load) that pop up another page, as shown here:

```
$( '.modal' ).colorbox(
{
    iframe          : true,
    slideshow       : false,
    title           : false,
    innerWidth      : 600,
    innerHeight     : 420,
    returnFocus     : false,
    slideshowStart  : "",
    slideshowStop   : "",
    current         : "",
    previous        : "",
    next            : "",
    close           : ""
});
```

This works...however, if I try to click on the client admin tab, and come back to the user admin tab and click on a link that launches `colorbox` again, it will load `colorbox` twice, with the same content, and will keep stacking colorboxes every time I come back to the user admin tab.

So, back to my point...how do I get jQuery UI to dump all of the resources including JS libaries of the current tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I screwed up. What I was doing was including colorbox (and other plugins) inside the tab, instead of JUST the html content.